# Qgis Summary of number of points

Tags: qgis, summarizing, aggregate-points

I have a csv with approx 1.3 million places. Some of these have the same coordinates.

My question is:
Is it possible to get visible summary on the point if it has maybe 100 points in the same place. I would like it to be visible as below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is just an example of making a count, already explained by @GeoBar.

QGIS 2.18 offers a function `count()` in Aggregates group.

Create a new field by an expression `count( "pid", group_by:= geomToWKT($geometry))` ("pid" can be any field name) .

[image]

And then categorize the point according to the `count`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use the information of your attribute table. If it is accessible, you can make a count of the points with presence in more than one records and then create a new field **which will be the counter** of the total appearance of each of your points. Then you can use this as a label. Of course,prior to this you may remove duplicating rows but at all cases keep the new field of your counter to use it in your symbology. 
Hope this helped.

Comment: this grouping/counting could be done also in SQL or MS Access as group by - count function.